# Custom Windows DPI (125%) cause underscore symbol lost in all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE)

Tags: windows-7, display, browser, dpi

I set my Windows 7 DPI to 125% , and started to see this problem:

[image: the underscore sign is lost (it happened in both Firefox and Chrome)]

Anybody knows the fix for it ?

Comment: When you copy it and paste it into notepad etc does the _ appear?

Comment: Which browser(s) does it affect?  Is it only on that page, or are there many examples where it happens?  Have you checked if the page's styling is forcing a line height (in pixels)?

Comment: Try `Ctrl + (plus)` and `Ctrl - (minus)` when in your browser

Comment: @ECarterYoung: notepad is showing the underscore sign

Comment: @techie007: all browsers are affected. FYI this is the CSS I got (it's from Google Big Query page):

    >font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;
    >font-size: 12.800000190734863px;
    >font-style: normal;
    >font-variant: normal;
    >font-weight: normal;
    >height: auto;
    >line-height: 15.600000381469727px;

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I knew Zoom-in, Zoom-out may fix, but is there any way to force proper rendering so that at page load, it should show properly.